# Overloaded with current from USB port... Causing problems with my data transfers on that port?

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb

I was fiddling around and had connected an microcontroller to the usb port on the computer, and after connecting multiple stuff up to it, i got the message on windows that went something like "unusual current draw on usb port". It seems to have detected it and disabled it self. Nice... sort of.

I can power on stuff on that usb port, and even do file transfers etc on that port. But it seems very unreliable for the file transfers. Uploading something to the microcontroller for example gives me midways error about the usb port/peripheral not working.

So the question is, did i partially fry my usb port?
Or is there maybe a reactivate button of some sort that i need to go looking for in windows10?

Thanks beforehand! :D

--EDIT more specific details

Computer: Legion T530-28ICB

The setup that i believe fried the port was, ESP32 connected with usb to computer. The ESP32 had a 12V DC motor that was controlled from an external 12V powersupply to power it by switching on a transistor. Now when the DC motor stalled, a much higher current was drawn into the DC Motor from the ESP32 to the transistor and there after the usb port powering the ESP32 itself was deactivated i think :O

Comment: Have you done a cold boot since? Devices asking for too much power should be a simple 'no, you can't' & nothing more.

Comment: I have tried that :O, what is really frustating is everything such as usb file transfers etc... works flawless. But the flashing of a microcontroller(uploading files to it) does not work. We don't need to go in details about microcontrollers it was just an example, but i am confident that something is not 100% functional with that port, since the microcontroller does work on the other ports flawlessly.

Comment: How are you powering the microcontroller? If you don't have a source of power other then the PC, that's probably the issue.

Comment: Connecting arbitrary "a microcontroller" with "multiple stuff connected to it" to unspecified PC with unknown USB port design... Are you serious asking this question without specifying NOTHING??

Comment: @Ale..chenski sorry, did not want to go in details about microcontrollers in this stackexchange and confuse people XD


Well the structure was, ESP32 connected with usb to computer. The ESP32 had a 12V DC motor that was controlled from an external 12V powersupply to power it by switching on a transistor. Now when the DC motor stalled, a much higher current was drawn into the DC Motor from the ESP32 to the transistor and there after the usb port powering the ESP32 itself was deactivated i think :O

Comment: If your PC mainboard has polyfuses as USB VBUS overcurrent protection and you did  have a real overcurrent such that the port VBUS went away, restoring the nominal low impedance of the polyfuse might take days or even weeks. For now you likely have some voltage drop across the unrecovered polyfuse and the USB power might be marginal. Without details of your power consumption and actual measurements it is impossible to say much.

Comment: @Ale..chenski You indeed may be on the correct track i believe, i can take on multimeter and "try" to go through by comparing the usb ports later :D
***************With your theory it could very well explain why normal small file transfers work and uploading stuff to the microcontroller that probably needs very exact communication timings could suffer enough that it breaks interrupts in the midway.
***********Thank you for the guideline :)